# Tensor product of 3 arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, tensor

I have an equation to count, that looks like this:

```
F(a,b) = sum(c=1...n, a*b*c[i])
```

I can count it this way:

```
for a=
  for b=
    for c=
    F(a,b)=F(a,b)+a*b*c
    end
  end
end
```

But I've heard, that on big arrays matlab "freezes" on nested loops. So I can do it this way:

```
a=(1:n)';
b=1:n2;
Fs=a*b;
for c=
   F=F+Fs*c;
end
```

But I want to solve this problem without any visible cycle. So I can create three orthogonal arrays of a,b,c tensor product them to get 3-D array, and then use sum function by third dimension.

```
a(:,1,1)=1:3;
b(1,:,1)=4:6;
c(1,1,:)=7:9;
d=tensorprod (a,b,2,1)
e=tensorprod (d,c);
```

But I ran into tensor multiplication problem in matlab. `e` has to be 3x3x3 array, but it is 3x3x1x1x3 array. It is correct and all, and even

```
g=sum(e,5);
```

returns matrix, but I don't understand why the third dimension has moved to the fifth

Comment: `But I've heard, that on big arrays matlab "freezes" on nested loops` -> Where have you heard this? MATLAB does fine with big loops, but they're not always necessary. It's often easier to get _something_ working with loops first, otherwise you're doing [premature optimisation](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/) at the expense of having a [mcve]. Do you have something which works with a loop? Is it too slow? You could show us that, presumably it's not too slow for some small input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that a no loop version is better. Using a broadcast (Matlab took that from Fortran and numpy), you could do it without loop, but I think the java JIT compiler of matlab could give better results with simple loops, nevertheless, a no-loop version could be

```
n2=3;
n2=4;
n3=5;
a=1:n1;
b=1:n2;
Fs=a'.*b;
F=zeros(size(Fs))
for c=1:n3
   F=F+Fs*c;
end
# the broadcast : all dimensions equal to one will be duplicate
# for the other tensor : after that we contract the tensor along the 
# third dimension
F2 = sum(Fs(:,:,1) .* reshape(1:n3,1,1,5), 3)
norm(F2-F,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your loop, this should give the desired sum.

```
a = 1:3;
b = 4:6;
c = 7:9;
F = a' * b * sum(c) 

F = 
    96   120   144
   192   240   288
   288   360   432
```

Comment: If I test this code, the resultat is wrong, but mathematically I do not see why il would be illegal to put a'*b outer of the sum.

Comment: I've used a bad example, my wrong. The real equation ( it counts radiation pattern) is more complicated, and has more parts, so I cannot do it this way, but as my problem was in tensor dimension, I've decided not to use the whole in this MWE

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with vectors and a dot product (inner product):

```
a=1:3;
b=4:6;
c=7:9;
D=dot(a,b);
E=sum(D*c)

E =

   768
```

Comment: Answer has to be matrix, so I need outer product, not inner